# Microsoft graph api - I want to list all the meetings/ appoint ments a user has during the day

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Currently i am doing this

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//users/emailaddress/calendar/events?$filter=(start/dateTime 
ge  '2019-07-11')  and (start/dateTime lt  '2019-07-12')
```

But i am not sure if i am calling the correct api.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use simpler statements:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/emailaddress/calendar/events?$filter=start/dateTime ge '2019-07-11' and start/dateTime lt '2019-07-12'
```

You could have a quick test in [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).